# Python: An integer is required. Where? Why?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this brief code snippet:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    row["last_check"] = last_check_ts
    row_filtered = {
        k: v.replace('\r', '') for k, v in row.iteritems() if v is not None
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
k: v.replace('\r', '') for k, v in row.iteritems() if v is not None
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What am I doing wrong? Exactly what is supposed to be an integer?

Edit:

This is what `rows` looks like printed on console:

```
[{'COD_PER_FISICA': None, 'INCLUIDO_POR': 'FU', 'MODIFICADO_POR': None, 'ES_FISICA': 'N', 'COD_PERSONA': '37470', 'NOMBRE': 'BLABLA', 'COD_PER_JURIDICA': '37470', 'FECHA_MODIFICACION': None, 'FECHA_INCLUSION': datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 7, 18, 22, 13)},
{'COD_PER_FISICA': None, 'INCLUIDO_POR': 'FU', 'MODIFICADO_POR': 'FOO', 'ES_FISICA': 'N', 'COD_PERSONA': '37471', 'NOMBRE': 'blablabla', 'COD_PER_JURIDICA': '37471', 'FECHA_MODIFICACION': datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 2, 12, 14, 35), 'FECHA_INCLUSION': datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 7, 18, 22, 13)},
{'COD_PER_FISICA': None, 'INCLUIDO_POR': 'FU', 'MODIFICADO_POR': None, 'ES_FISICA': 'N', 'COD_PERSONA': '37472', 'NOMBRE': 'blablabala', 'COD_PER_JURIDICA': '37472', 'FECHA_MODIFICACION': None, 'FECHA_INCLUSION': datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 7, 18, 22, 13)},
{'COD_PER_FISICA': None, 'INCLUIDO_POR': 'FU', 'MODIFICADO_POR': None, 'ES_FISICA': 'N', 'COD_PERSONA': '37473', 'NOMBRE': 'blablabla', 'COD_PER_JURIDICA': '37473', 'FECHA_MODIFICACION': None, 'FECHA_INCLUSION': datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 7, 18, 22, 13)},
{'COD_PER_FISICA': None, 'INCLUIDO_POR': 'FU', 'MODIFICADO_POR': 'blablablaA', 'ES_FISICA': 'N', 'COD_PERSONA': '37474', 'NOMBRE': 'blablabla', 'COD_PER_JURIDICA': '37474', 'FECHA_MODIFICACION': datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 2, 12, 14, 19), 'FECHA_INCLUSION': datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 7, 18, 22, 13)}]
```

Comment: can you post the original data set as well?

Comment: Does that happen on the first time through the loop? It might help to dump out `i` at the start of the loop to track. Also, it might help to break down the list comprehension into a discrete for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move this line:

```
row["last_check"] = last_check_ts
```

Below your dict comprehension. You can reproduce this as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
rows = {'a': None, 'b': 'some_str\r', 'c': datetime.utcnow()}
{k: v.replace('\r', '') for k, v in rows.items() if v is not None}
```

You're adding a timestamp to your dict *before* looping over it, so one of the times you're calling `v.replace('\r', '')` the `v` object is actually a datetime. `datetime` objects do indeed have a [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) method, but you're treating it like a string and therefore calling it with the wrong signature.

Comment: Brilliant deduction given the incomplete information in the question.

Comment: I've updated my question showing the content of `rows` just to clarify.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just wrap the `v.replace` call with a check that the object is a string? E.g., `v.replace('\r', '') if isinstance(v, basestring) else v` in Python 2.x; `v.replace('\r', '') if isinstance(v, str) else v` in Python 3.x. That will be more robust since then you guard against any other rogue data types which happen to be in the row.